# Get column name based on column value dynamically

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, case

I have a table with "User Name", "Brand" and "Value" as columns. Each Manager and their associates are responsible for max 3 brand and these brands can change from manager to manager. Right now User name, Brand and their value are in row format like below.

```
           User Name    Brand Name  Value
             User 1             Puma    10
             User 1            Adidas   20
             User 1             Nike    30
             User 2             Puma    40
             User 2           Adidas    50
             User 2             Nike    60
             User 3             Puma    70
             User 3           Adidas    80
             User 3             Nike    90
```

Using a "case-when" I achieved below, but the problem is, these brand can change based on the manager. Example. Manager -1 can be responsible for Puma, Nike, Adidas but Manager -2 can be responsible for X, Y, Z Brands.

```
            User Name   Brand -1    Brand -2  Brand -3
             User 1       10      20        30
             User 2       40      50        60
             User 3       70      80        90
```

My desired state is to get the Brand name in column format like below.

For Manager - 1

```
            User Name   PUMA      ADIDAS      NIKE
             User 1          10    20              30
             User 2          40    50              60
             User 3          70    80              90
```

For Manager -2

```
            User Name    X      Y       Z
             User 1          10    20       30
             User 2          40    50       60
             User 3          70    80       90
```

I want actual 3 brand names as columns dynamically and not Brand-1, Brand-2, Brand -3. I can hard code these brand names but as I said they can vary from manager to manager but at a time one manager.

Comment: how you are storing managers information?

Comment: I am Using Postgres SQL.

Comment: @ch2019 my report is taking manager id as a parameter. So one manager at a time (3 brands at a time).

Answer (score 0):

Pivotting can be achieved in multiple ways,

1) using pivot function
2) using XML function
3) dynamic SQLs
4) using cursors

Assuming you are using Oracle SQL database all the above can be applicable please investigate more on the above. If its otherwise few of the above will be applicable along with other options with respect to your database tool.

Comment: I am using Postgres SQL